# Use google analytics to capture touch events?

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-analytics, analytics

Can you use google analytics to capture ios touch events such as taps and swipes in the browsers? Is it also possible to report back on the x and y coordinates of where it happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a Mobile JavaScript library like [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/).

It has a jQuery-like API, and methods specific to touch events.

So, you could do things like:

```
$(".slider").swipe(function(){
    _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Gesture", "Swipe"]);
});
```

Check out the documentation here: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto